# Any way to force two elements to stay next to each other on the same row with JQuery Mobile?

Tags: html, jquery-mobile

I want to have two elements stay on the same row.

Right now I have this code:

```
<fieldset data-role="controlgroup" data-type="horizontal">
   <label for="textinput">Text:</label>
   <input type="text" id="textinput"/>
   <input type="button" id="searchbutton" data-icon="search"  data-iconpos="notext" onclick="function()"/>
</fieldset>
```

This works. The label, the input field and the button will all be on the same row as long as you view it in fullscreen in your computer browser. But if we make the window smaller, all three elements will be shown on one row each. Is there any way to make the label appear on one row, and the input field + button on the row below?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to override the jQM enhancements:

- http://jsfiddle.net/E4EVT/10/
- http://jsfiddle.net/E4EVT/36/ (Using the grid layout)
- http://jsfiddle.net/E4EVT/42/ (Using the table layout)

JS

```
$('#textinput2').css('width','60%').css('display','inline');
```

HTML

```
<div>
    <!-- use span instead of label -->
    <span>Text:</span>
    <input type="text" id="textinput2"/>
    <br />
    <input type="button" id="searchbutton2" data-icon="search"  data-iconpos="notext" onclick="function()"/>
</div>
```

I think you might want to look into the grid layout jQM offers

- http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0rc1/docs/content/content-grids.html

Comment: Look at this example:
http://jsfiddle.net/E4EVT/31/ That is how I want the final result to be. The 1st one when the window is big. And the 2nd one when the window is small.

Comment: Updated my answer, look at the grid layout options: http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0rc1/docs/content/content-grids.html

Comment: Yes, the gridlayout does what I want, kind of. But it also means the input field + button won't align with the other input fields in the same form. It makes it look kind of ugly :/ Maybe it's simply time to realize that jQM is a bitch when it comes to design.

Comment: You could also use the table layout: http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0rc1/docs/content/content-html.html (view source) but the reason why it's a little challenging to have a custom layout in jQM is that they wanted to offer the same look and feel to a multitude of devices, having custom code will also look different on other devices as well

Comment: The way I finally "solved" it was like this: http://jsfiddle.net/E4EVT/45/ Thanks for the help. Probably wouldn't have gotten there without you.

Answer (score 3):

For Jquery Mobile 1.2.0

```
<div class="ui-grid-a" >
<div class="ui-block-a"><input type="text" /></div>
<div class="ui-block-b"><input type="text" /></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

you need to add attribute data-inline="true" to the input elements.

Comment: and try to put them in spans maybe..?

Answer (score 0):

CSS:

```
label {
   display: block;
}
input {
    padding: 2px;
    width: 100px;
}
.wrap {
    width: 212px; /* the width of twice your input (plus borders) */
}
```

And your HTML:

```
<fieldset data-role="controlgroup" data-type="horizontal">
   <label for="textinput">Text:</label>
   <div class="wrap">
      <input type="text" id="textinput"/>
      <input type="button" id="searchbutton" data-icon="search"  data-iconpos="notext" onclick="function()"/>
   </div>
</fieldset>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ahallicks/BWsdk/

Edit:

Sorry, misread your question! If you want them all on the same line to start with use the following CSS:

```
label {
    float: left;
    margin-right: 12px;
}
input {
    padding: 2px;
    width: 100px;
}
.wrap {
    float: left;
    width: 212px; /* the width of twice your input (plus borders) */
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ahallicks/E4EVT/

Comment: Sadly, this won't do the trick. Since I am using JQuery Mobile, the JQuery Mobile css will still "do its magic" and put each element on a line each. I want it to simply adjust the size of the text input so that the button will fit next to it.